# Azure SQL External Table alternatives

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Azure external tables between two azure sql databases on the same server don't perform well. This is known. I've been able to improve performance by defining a view from which the external table is defined. This works if the view can limit the data set returned. But this partial solution isn't enough. I'd love a way to at least nightly, move all the data that has been inserted or updated from the full set of tables from the one database (dbo schema) to the second database (pushing into the altdbo schema). I think Azure data factory will let me do this, but I haven't figured out how. Any thoughts / guidance? The copy option doesn't copy over table schemas or updates

Comment: Hi Peter Beery, welcome to Stack Overflow, I help reopen the question. If my answer is helpful for you, please mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory [Mapping Data Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview) can help you achieve that.

Using the [AlterRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row) active and select an [uptade method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-database#sink-transformation) in Sink:

[image]

This can help you copy the new inserted or updated data to the another Azure SQL database based on the Key Column.

1. **Alter Row**: Use the Alter Row transformation to set insert, delete, update, and
   upsert policies on rows.
2. **Update method**: Determines what operations are allowed on your
   database destination. The default is to only allow inserts. To
   update, upsert, or delete rows, an alter-row transformation is
   required to tag rows for those actions. For updates, upserts and
   deletes, a key column or columns must be set to determine which row
   to alter.

Hope this helps.